# $\int_0^1\frac{1-\cos x}{x} \, dx-\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x} \, dx=\gamma, \\ \gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/2+\cdots+1/n-\ln n)$

Tags: integration

Prove:$$\int_0^1\frac{1-\cos x}{x} \, dx-\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x} \, dx=\gamma, \\ \gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/2+\cdots+1/n-\ln n)$$

I try to use the Taylor expansion of $1-\cos x$ and exchange the order of 'integral sign' and 'sum sign', but I don't know how to deal with the latter integral.

Comment: Ok,I see.Thank you!

Comment: Or see formula (3.20) in Ch. 2 of [Olver, 1974](https://www.google.com/search?q=Asymptotics+and+Special+Functions+F.W.J.+Olver&oq=Asymptotics+and+Special+Functions+F.W.J.+Olver&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQRRg8MgYIAhBFGDwyBggDEEUYPDIGCAQQLhhA0gEIMTY0N2owajGoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis :Sorry to disturb you.Are you a professor at the Michigan technology university?I am fortunate that a professor has answered my doubts. I am just a low-level undergraduate student in mathematic.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis:Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Too long for a comment** (an absolutely trivial problem)

Use the rearrangement

$$\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^{\infty}(1-\cos(x))e^{-s x}\textrm{d}x -\int_1^{\infty} e^{-s x} \textrm{d}x\right)\textrm{d}s,$$
which leads to
$$\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{s(1+s^2)}-\frac{e^{-s}}{s}\right)\textrm{d}s=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{s(1+s)}-\frac{e^{-s}}{s}\right)\textrm{d}s=\gamma,$$
since we have the (absolutely trivial) result
$$\int_0^{\infty} \left(e^{-x}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^s}\right)\frac{1}{x}\textrm{d}x=\psi(s),$$
which follows immediately by exploiting the simple fact that $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}\textrm{d}x=\log\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$, and done. And you want to remember that $\psi(1)=-\gamma$.

(An absolute) **End of story**

*Remember that was meant to be only a comment.*